# How can the @Target annotation be used on itself in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE}) // line 3
public @interface Target { 
    ElementType[] value();
}
```

The code above is the source code of `Target` in Java. How can the target annotation be defined in this way? It seems like it shouldn't be allowed on line 3, because `Target` hasn't yet been defined. Or it is a data structure that can be nested just like the code section below?

```java
public class BinaryTreeNode {
    public int val;
    public BinaryTreeNode leftChild;
    public BinaryTreeNode rightChild;

    public BinaryTreeNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTreeNode lChild = new BinaryTreeNode(1);
        BinaryTreeNode rChild = new BinaryTreeNode(2);

        BinaryTreeNode bt = new BinaryTreeNode(0);
        bt.leftChild = lChild;
        bt.rightChild = rChild;
    }
}
```

I have tried to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking on Stack Overflow you tend to learn a lot more if you try stuff. So, let's do that:

```
> cat Test.java

@Test
@interface Test {}

> javac Test.java
```

Runs fine, no complains from javac. So, yes, you can annotate an `@interface` definition with itself.

Javac doesn't just parse line by line. If it did, how would this work then:

```
class Test {

 void foo() {
   bar(); // wait! This hasn't been defined yet!
 }

 void bar() {}
}
```

Except.. that works fine.

Javac first parses the file, turning it from a sack of characters into a tree structure. It does that for all of the source files you tell it to compile.

*Then* it 'attributes' all these nodes. This is the phase where `java.lang.String` turns from "select thingie 'String' on node `java.lang`, which is a 'Select thingie 'lang' on node `java`, which is an "Ident `java`" - into 'a reference to the type `java.lang.String`. This phase needs a classpath.

*Then* it starts compiling details that do not immediately matter for the previous phases, such as actually parsing method bodies and, yes, annotations.